# jhipster session timeout configuration

Tags: spring, security, angularjs, jhipster

I downloaded JHipster from git and tried to understand how to configure session timeout but couldn't find any `web.xml` or java-based class for that.

Could you please help me figure out how can I configure `session` timeout for example to be 20 min?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a Spring Boot configuration.

You can configure it in your `application-*.yml` file:

```
server:
    port: 8080
    address: localhost
    sessionTimeout: 20000
```

Comment: This seems to have been moved to the server.servlet.session.timeout parameter in recent Springboot versions

Answer (score 3):

in your application-*.yml file:

```
server:
    port: 8080
    address: localhost
    sessionTimeout: 20000
```

is OK for 20 minutes but if you want to have more 30 minutes your access Token validity ("tokenValidityInSeconds" attribute) is 30 minutes by default. You can configue this attribute in **application.yml** file.

Example for 3 hours = 180 minutes = 10800 secondes:

```
authentication:
    oauth:
        clientid: testspsyapp
        secret: mySecretOAuthSecret
        # Token is valid 3 hours
        tokenValidityInSeconds: 10800
```

Do not to forget the changes "sessionTimeout" attribut to your application-*.yml file :)

```
server:
    port: 8080
    address: localhost
    sessionTimeout: 180000
```

Comment: is this sessionTimeout work for Oauth application when its expire ? because I am looking a solution for oauth application session time out.

Comment: @Mohankumar Rathinam, you need 2 param (tokenValidityInSeconds and   sessionTimeout)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but the answer needed to be updated as the config setting being called is deprecated.  You'll want to use this instead.

```
    server:
        port: 8080
        servlet:
          session:
            timeout: 60s
```